# Transforming Data using 2D Costum Transformation in Arcmap 10.2 for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, 2d

I have ArcMap layers of roads, buildings etc. in one reference system (Israel_TM).
I need to transfrom all this data (while keeping the topology) to pixel-space "reference system". 
I have already calculated the transformation parameters (using Matlab) of a Conformal Transformation (2D) between the two reference systems: Israel_TM to Pixels. It it a 4 parameters transformation I have: 1xRotation, 1xScale, 2xTranslations. 
How can I create a user-defined 2D transformation and use it to transform all my data to Pixel-space ?
All I could find is Helmert 7-Par. transformation or other 3D transformation methods under in Layer properties-->Coordinate System-->Transformation.
I tried to use the Toolbox for this but couldn't find anything relevant.